# Can the iPhone SDK obtain the Wi-Fi SSID currently connected to?

Tags: iphone, ios, wifi

In the iPhone SDK I don't see the same `SCDynamicStore` used on Mac OS X to get the SSID name that your wireless network is currently connected to isn't available.

Is there a way to get the SSID name that the iPhone is currently connected to?

I see some apps do it ([Easy Wi-Fi for AT&T](http://itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStore.woa/wa/viewSoftware?id=296273148&mt=8) for one) but I can't find how it's done in the iPhone SDK docs. A private or unpublish method would be acceptable just as a proof of concept (although I know that likely wouldn't make it to the AppStore).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is now possible (iOS 4.1+) via the [Captive Network API](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/SystemConfiguration/Reference/CaptiveNetworkRef/Reference/reference.html).

See [an example of how to use it on this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5198716/iphone-get-ssid-without-private-library).

**This is not a private API.**

Answer (score 6):

After digging around I found the anser to this.  There are unpublished APIs in the Preferences framework. For examples of this one can look at the [Stumbler code](http://code.google.com/p/iphone-wireless/source/browse/trunk/Stumbler/MSNetworksManager.m) hosted on Google Code.

I filed a radar with Apple (#6407431/[OpenRadar version](http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=306)) that was marked as a duplicate of #5814810).  If you want this officially supported then please also file a radar at [bugreport.apple.com](http://bugreport.apple.com).

Update: The above Stumbler code is for 1.x revision iPhone OS SDK. For iPhone OS 2.0 and beyond developers will have to look in PrivateFrameworks/Apple80211.Framework and all that implies.

Answer (score 4):

Try this code,

```
#import <SystemConfiguration/CaptiveNetwork.h>

CFArrayRef myArray = CNCopySupportedInterfaces();
CFDictionaryRef myDict = CNCopyCurrentNetworkInfo(CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(myArray, 0));
NSDictionary *ssidList = (__bridge NSDictionary*)myDict;
NSString *SSID = [ssidList valueForKey:@"SSID"];
```

Comment: Noting that you'll need a null check on myArray