# Accessing iPhone WiFi Information via SDK

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, wifi

Is there a way using the iPhone SDK to get WiFi information? Things like Signal Strength, WiFi Channel and SSID are the main things I'm looking for.

Only interested in Wifi info, not cellular.

Comment: check out the apple site, they have widgets and api's exposed for this.

Comment: Yes I know there is an API - just not sure how to get Signal Strength programatically

Comment: Any idea how to use these calls?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5198716/iphone-get-ssid-without-private-library

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Based on [this](http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=306) bug report and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339089/can-the-iphone-sdk-obtain-the-wi-fi-ssid-currently-connected-to) SO question, I'm guessing there's no supported way to do this atm.

EDIT: Chris mentioned WiFinder, which prompted me to do a little more digging.  According to the WiFinder author's [blog](http://larsbergstrom.wordpress.com/2008/11/03/on-the-lack-of-wifinder-updates/) he used methods from the private Apple80211.framework.  (The framework mentioned in the above linked SO question.)  Apparently Apple will no longer allow these private API calls in apps, which is preventing him from updating WiFinder.

But, if you want to use them anyway, some kind folks have posted a list of discovered Apple80211 functions to [google code](http://code.google.com/p/iphone-wireless/wiki/Apple80211Functions).

It looks like [`Apple80211GetInfoCopy`](http://code.google.com/p/iphone-wireless/wiki/Apple80211GetInfoCopy) might do the trick.

Comment: Until a few weeks ago there were an application called WifiTrak (bitrino.com/wifitrak/support.html) on the appstore which displayed a list of all available wi-fi hotspots in range. It has however been pulled from the appstore, so even though it appeared that this is possible it might not be acceptable by Apple for whatever reason.

Comment: it not use for iphone 5S OS7

Comment: The Blog article is cached here: https://web.archive.org/web/20090220171732/http://larsbergstrom.wordpress.com/2008/11/03/on-the-lack-of-wifinder-updates/

Answer (score 13):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4304942/cncopycurrentnetworkinfo-is-returning-bad-data) it's actually possible since iOS 4.1.

The function is called: [CNCopyCurrentNetworkInfo](https://developer.apple.com/reference/systemconfiguration/1614126-cncopycurrentnetworkinfo)()

Hope that helps.

Comment: But not enough information. I hope Apple releases some API even for their own Airports.

Comment: With iPhone 5c os7.1 this method not use full. I try and get CFDictionaryRef is null

Comment: it not use full for iphone 5S os 7.1 , help me get it

Comment: This is very misleading. This API is not for any WiFi network such as your home or office network. This is only for captive networks such as networks that require user interaction (like opening a webpage for capturing username and password) before connecting to the Internet. You might have seen the captive networks in hotels and restaurants.

Answer (score 1):

The WiFinder iPhone application does it somehow...

Comment: Nice find. See my edits for the WiFinder authors issues w/using the private Apple80211.framework

Comment: WiFinder is using a database of WiFi's whose locations are stored in the database. IMHO this is not the answer to the initial question, because the WiFinder App just helps to locate the user based on his GPS position and determines the distance to the WiFi stations stored in the database.

Comment: The API was closed by Apple so the app was changed since my initial post.  It no longer gets signal strength info for WiFi.