# Detecting wifi network change in iPad

Tags: iphone, networking, ipad, wifi

I have an iPad application which requires me to stream a video to a user only if he is connected to a particular wifi network. If his wifi network changes, I need to stop streaming.
Is there any way to know that the wifi network that the user is connected to has changed?
Are there any public APIs that can give me the SSID of the wifi network I am connected to or the VSS ID or the MAC address of the router?

Thanks and Rgrds,
Hetal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no supported way to do this, but it is possible.

See this question for more details:
[Accessing iPhone WiFi Information via SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/351954/accessing-iphone-wifi-information-via-sdk#412548)

Comment: It is possible. But this can done using a private API, which when Apple comes to know will pull your app from App Store.