# CNCopyCurrentNetworkInfo() is returning bad data

Tags: iphone, ios4, network-programming

Apple introduced the CNCopyCurrentNetworkInfo() function in OS 4.1.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/SystemConfiguration/Reference/CaptiveNetworkRef/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/kCNNetworkInfoKeySSIDData

According to the documentation it should:

> Return the current network info for a given network interface.

However, when used it seems to return the correct SSID (readable network name) but a garbage BSSID(the MAC address of the Wireless Access Point). I have tried this connected to multiple different networks with two different iPads and the results are the same.

On my home network, the function returns:
*{
BSSID = "0:19:db:8:5c:cc";
SSID = "Das Boot";
SSIDDATA = <44617320 426f6f74>;
}*

In reality, the BSSID of my router is *0:4:ed:66:81:xx* where the *xx* definitely is not *cc*

Does anyone have experience using this function and have I missed something obvious (more likely) or is this an Apple bug (much less likely) ?

Any input is greatly appreciated,

Nicke.

Comment: Don't post the real BSSID online. Crackers can do things with that info.