# What information is returned by CNCopyCurrentNetworkInfo() function in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ipad, wifi

I am developing an app in which I want to get the information of the Wi-Fis like signal strength etc. in the area.

While doing some digging I found out [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/SystemConfiguration/Reference/CaptiveNetworkRef/Reference/reference.html) in Apple Documentation.
It does not specifies what information is returned by the function.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4304942/cncopycurrentnetworkinfo-is-returning-bad-data) question here on SO reveals that it gives SSID and BSSID.

Can anybody tell me what other information this function does return? Or is that it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

from code I found it returns, as you've already told the **SSID**, the **BSSID** but also the **SSIDDATA**.
SSIDDATA being the hex representation of the SSID.

That's it.

No way getting signal strength, wifi security, etc from the public API.