# Checking Network Availability

Tags: iphone, network-connection

I use reacheability class for checking my network connectivity in my app...

```
Reachability *reach = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection]; 
    NetworkStatus netStatus = [reach currentReachabilityStatus];    
    if (netStatus==NotReachable)
    {
        NSLog(@"NR");
    }
```

I need to find when the network status change (i.e when the network status changes from reachable to notreachable  and vice versa).

Is there any delegates to find this thinks, Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used this flag `kReachabilityChangedNotification` to find the change in network status and passed that to a `NSNotificationCenter`

Here is the code:

```
NSString *host = @"https://www.apple.com"; // Put your host here

        // Set up host reach property
       hostReach = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostname:host];

                          // Enable the status notifications
                          [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self  selector:@selector(reachabilityChanged:) name:kReachabilityChangedNotification object:nil];
                           [hostReach startNotifier];

   - (void) reachabilityChanged: (NSNotification* )note
{
    Reachability *reachability = [note object];
    NSParameterAssert([reachability isKindOfClass:[Reachability class]]);
    if (reachability == hostReach) {
        Reachability *reach = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection]; 
        NetworkStatus netStatus = [reach currentReachabilityStatus];    
        if (netStatus==NotReachable)
        {
            NSLog(@"notreacheable");
        }
        else {
            NSLog(@"reacheable");
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]postNotificationName:@"startUpdatingTable" object:nil];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to make use of Apple's Reachability class. [Here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html) is a sample App by Apple.

and also check this links.

> http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/iphone-snippet-detecting-network-status

Comment: Well thanks for ur answer..... But hw my app can trace the changes in network status??

Comment: add the timer in applications delegate and call the network connections method. like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4538168/how-to-check-internet-status-in-iphone

Comment: Use NSNotificationCenter and try to call network connections method in your view controller view

Comment: Also checked this link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/339089/can-the-iphone-sdk-obtain-the-wi-fi-ssid-currently-connected-to                           http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5198716/iphone-get-ssid-without-private-library     may be helped you

Answer (score -1):

use **Reachability"** class

add flooding method in app delegate  so you can use this method any ware in project

```
#import "Reachability.h"
-(BOOL)isHostAvailable
{
    //return NO; // force for offline testing
    Reachability *hostReach = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
    NetworkStatus netStatus = [hostReach currentReachabilityStatus];
    return !(netStatus == NotReachable);
}
```

Comment: Well thanks for ur answer..... But hw my app can trace the changes in network status??