# Scanning wifi getting the power

Tags: iphone, wifi

I know this is an asked question, but I couldn't get an answer...
I want to scan the WiFi Access Points around me, getting the power of them. It is not for upload it to the appstore, so I don't care about private APIs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple iOS SDK does not contain interface to get the signal strength information of Wi-Fi OFFICIALLY.

Here is a related SO question: [Accessing iPhone WiFi Information via SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/351954/accessing-iphone-wifi-information-via-sdk)