# How to get surrounding networks with strength in iOS?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, wireless

Is there any frameworks for find out the surrounding networks and network strength. Please tell me if it is possible or not in ios 4/5/6. Either is there any sample code for this.

For example i am using in iPhone Airtel network. Based on Airtel network i need to find what are other networks in that particular area and what is the signal strength of that network.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as i know this cant be done using public API's. You need to use private API's check thi s out [MobileApple80211 framework](http://code.google.com/p/iphone-wireless/wiki/Apple80211Functions).

Yes it is possible. In fact there is an awesome 3rd Party library for this called [iPhone-Wireless](http://code.google.com/p/iphone-wireless/wiki/Stumbler)

This provides you -

1. view the wireless networks in your area.
2. signal strength of each network.

For iOS 5 you'll need a jailbroken iPhone. [Guvener Gokce](https://stackoverflow.com/users/80973/guvener-gokce) has a very educational blog post on this: [iPhone Wireless Scanner iOS5](http://blog.guvenergokce.com/iphone-wireless-scanner-ios5/170/)

Hope this helps but keep in mind that this library uses private API's and your app might get rejected from app store.

UPDATE: Check this out too - [Accessing iPhone WiFi Information via SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/351954/accessing-iphone-wifi-information-via-sdk)

Comment: Thank you so much, but i am unable to find the Apple80211 framework in ios 4. I am conforming by this link http://theiphonewiki.com/wiki/index.php?title=/System/Library/Frameworks

Comment: sorry i have put in what i am aware of.all of them point to private API access

Comment: so what did u end up using ?