# Can i get details of wifi networks near my iPhone? Scan all wifi networks near my iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, networking, wifi, signal-strength

I want to get the list of wifi network near my iPhone. Get the details such as signal strength,SSID , MAC Address from the wifi network, without using any 3rd party library (i do not want my app to be stuck off in any review process). please help me , i need to get this going soon.

Comment: As of iOS 7, MAC address access has been removed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Accessing iPhone WiFi Information via SDK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/351954/accessing-iphone-wifi-information-via-sdk)

Comment: its the mac address of the wifi access point , not of the device....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iPhone get a list of all SSIDs without private library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9684341/iphone-get-a-list-of-all-ssids-without-private-library)

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer… You can't by using public library. You sure can using private ones, but you don't want apple to reject your app.

Comment: What private libs will get RSSI signal strength of WIFI connection?

Comment: Then how they published this one ? https://itunes.apple.com/en/app/fing-network-scanner/id430921107?mt=8