# Getting wifi Router type in iOS

Tags: ios, ios7, ios6

I want to know if there is any iOS API available which can be used to find out what kind of router i am connected to.. for Ex:- if wifi router is a G type router or N type router.
My application have needs to identify the kind of router connected & based on that start proceeding to the next steps.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What's up with the down votes without even explaining the reason?

Comment: There is a CoreWLan framework for the MAC and one of the headers contain the wifi type.  An IOS version is probably part and parcel of the IOS core but not available to the 3rd party apps like the ones we make, I'd suggest bringing this up with Apple support because they may have an undocumented interface somewhere.

Comment: some people are just trigger happy in down voting, I think this is a valid question, important to know whether to allow particular types of network connection or disallow it because it will just result in bad user experience.

Comment: Thanks Paulo, But i am looking for an ios alternative.. if not in objective C i guess c code might be of use for me as well.. Any other pointers for ios?

Comment: is there any ioctl that can give you this info? or maybe something like what ifconfig shows? also, if you can get the MAC, you can identify the vendor of the router... perhaps that's helpful.

Comment: @nielsbot i need to find out the details programatically not by visiting the vendor website. also as per i know ios6.0 and above doesn't allows to find the mac address of wifi or iPad with public Apis

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that sort of info is send over a WiFi signal. Unless you hack into the router and pull its details.

Can you not just check the speed and determine N/G etc based on that?

Comment: IS there any way to find out the speed of a wifi router using iOS Api's. I tried google it but no answer found.

Comment: Well it seems to me that some Apps are able to analyze the network including routers so it may well be possible: https://itunes.apple.com/jp/app/lan-scan-network-device-scanner/id597541266?mt=8

Comment: I'd be very interested in knowing how they get that sort of information. Interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Did you see this thread,

[Accessing iPhone WiFi Information via SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/351954/accessing-iphone-wifi-information-via-sdk)

Iy mentions few external private API's to get Wifi information , have a look

Comment: I need public APIs not private one. Also AFAIK those private Api's doesn't work on latest iOS version anymore.