# How to detect and display available wifi networks near by my current location?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, wifi

I want to detect all the available wifi networks near by my current location and i have to list them in a tableview. I don't have any idea about this functionality. Anyone suggest me with right solution.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Welcome to SO.  What research have you done?  We are not a code writing service.  Please read the [SO Help](http://stackoverflow.com/help)

Comment: i didn't find any solution for my question in your research so only i posted my question here for better solution, and i know it is not a code writing service

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iPhone get a list of all SSIDs without private library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9684341/iphone-get-a-list-of-all-ssids-without-private-library)

Answer (score 1):

You can't by using public library. You sure can using private ones, but you don't want apple to reject your app. if u using any private api try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/351954/accessing-iphone-wifi-information-via-sdk)

Comment: Hey hi thanks for your quick reply, this app  requirement is not for publishing in app store.

Comment: hmm, then fine Hari use CFNetworking framework, if my answer is fine, give a up vote my answer