# iOS Application Rejection - ----- MFi - Self-Certification -----

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, mfi

I have developed the application for Funeral home. The basic concept of that application is to scan the finger of dead people and then fill the form. After that all those data are sent to server. For scanning process, I am using third party library, Onyxkit which does not require any External Hardware connection. Apple rejected the application by giving below reason under Resolution Center, [image: Please review attached image]

Can any one guide me, how to deal with this problem?

Comment: if u use any private n/w just like find the near wifi , the apple has not approved your app

Comment: need ref http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26436923/how-to-detect-and-display-available-wifi-networks-near-by-my-current-location/26437032#26437032

Comment: No. It is just simple app. It collects the data from users (with their permission) and send to our server using SOAP based XML.

Comment: what is Mfi,and what is the purpose that..

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/programs/mfi/

Comment: http://www.diamondfortress.com/