# Work with wifi in my iphone application

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Please answer me, How to obtain information about wifi networks in my iphone application, Does apple provide API for this, Can I change current wifi connection without exit from my application?

Answer (score 1):

There is no API for listing available wifi networks or programmatically changing to a different one. The closest way you *might* be able to get a list would be to use an NSNetServiceBrowser and try to discover all tcp services. I doubt that'll work, but it might be worth a shot.

Comment: Thanks, I already use NSNetServiceBrowser but this only for Bonjour level, I want get access to low level. Also I see next application in app store, this app can find and get info about wifi network, name of this app wififofam.

Answer (score 0):

I was curious about this as well. The posts below explain things in more detail. There are undocumented ways of getting WiFi information, but it'll get your app rejected on the iTunes Store.

- [Can the iPhone SDK obtain the Wi-Fi SSID currently connected to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339089/can-the-iphone-sdk-obtain-the-wi-fi-ssid-currently-connected-to/376053#376053)
- [Accessing iPhone WiFi Information via SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/351954/accessing-iphone-wifi-information-via-sdk/412548#412548)

Comment: Thanks for answer, I try use Apple80211.framework, but this framework exists only on 2.0.x iphone OS. In 3.0.x I did  not see this framework, also i see application in app store which can obtain wifi ssid and can switch between wifi networks. Application is wififofam, and this app was not rejected by app store, may be creators of this app is very lucky :). Interesting what they use to obtain info about wifi networks?