# Get wifi name uses on iphone app

Tags: iphone

I am new to the iphone app developing. Now i am creating an app which uses wireless network. In that i want to get the name of wireless network which we are using currently from our iphone application and display it in a label. Is it possible to get, if yes means please help me. Thank in advance.

Comment: This question was already asked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/339089/can-the-iphone-sdk-obtain-the-wi-fi-ssid-currently-connected-to