# how to make an iphone application which works only in a specific wifi network

Tags: iphone

hi  i want to make an application which could work only a particular ip(network).

not in other wifi reachable by iphone.

please help me in this.

thanks

Comment: Use the API to get the current network type and IP/subnet/gateway/SSID then deny functionality. Are you looking for specific code?

Comment: yes i am looking for  a specific code ...

Answer (score 1):

I was curious about this as well. The posts below explain things in more detail. There are undocumented ways of getting WiFi information, but it'll get your app rejected on the iTunes Store.

- [Can the iPhone SDK obtain the Wi-Fi SSID currently connected to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339089/can-the-iphone-sdk-obtain-the-wi-fi-ssid-currently-connected-to/376053#376053)
- [Accessing iPhone WiFi Information via SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/351954/accessing-iphone-wifi-information-via-sdk/412548#412548)